# Highcharts - Exporting with custom CSS unique to just the export

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, export

I am trying to overwrite a css setting, due to the series legend text+icon for the graph overlapping in export results - due them them not respecting spacing thus being too close when exported. Overall changes targeted at the legend can create a decent looking export result, but impacts the online version negatively, which is why I am trying to target just the export. (I am quite new to highcharts).

Looking for various answers has yielded different results (with no luck), among them the [suggestion](http://jsfiddle.net/d_paul/9xctmxo6/) to use a built in function, to create a class only for the export, than I can then target:

```
exporting: {
        chartOptions: {
          chart: {
            className: 'new-chart-class'
          }
        }
      },
```

If it worked it would be lovely, but sadly it does not generate a result (No error log, so unaware of what fails). The [chartOptions](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.chartOptions) has potential, but none seems to target the setting I want.

Another [suggestion](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wm5k0zna/), is also a no go, seeing as doesn't actually do anything different for the export (at least I can't get a result difference when trying it out).

I can't seem to find any specifics that targets that area only during export and also allows the style I wanted (for instance .highcharts-legend-item does allow styling, but only takes text targeted css and I don't want to affect things, other than the export). I was hoping for something similar to [sourceWidth](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.sourceWidth).

The page code as it is (setup to be easy to view, but edited to remove real data and without the custom js changes to the highchart js, that is causing the problem. It works with the standard includes (hence for the code below), but those are modified on my end (Meaning the real code  does not import from highcharts). Hence the hope to find a way so I target the export alone:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div class="csc-header csc-header-n2"><div class="accordionEditor">TitleText</div></div>

    <div class="rounded-shadow" style="background-color: white">
      <div id="container4" style="min-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 5px">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <style>
    @import 'https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css'
    /*.style-class .highcharts-legend-item text {
      word-spacing: 40px;
    }*/
    </style>
    
    <script>
      
      
      $(document).ready(function () {
        
      var buttons = Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems;
        
      var precipDays = {'Jan': 4, 'Feb': 4, 'Mar': 5, 'Apr': 5, 'Maj': 5, 'Jun': 5, 'Jul': 6, 'Aug': 6, 'Sep': 7, 'Okt': 7, 'Nov': 9, 'Dec': 7};
        
      
        
      Highcharts.setOptions({
            lang : {
            decimalPoint: ",",
            months: ["january", "february", "marts", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "oktober", "november", "december"],
            shortMonths: ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "maj", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "okt", "nov", "dec"],
            weekdays: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Thuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursdag", "Friday", "Saturday"],
            shortWeekdays: ["sun", "mon", "thu", "wed", "thur", "fri", "sat"],
            contextButtonTitle : "Graf menu",
            downloadJPEG : "JPEG billede",
            downloadPDF : "PDF",
            downloadPNG : "PNG",
            downloadSVG : "SVG",
            downloadCSV : "(CSV)",
            downloadXLS : "XLS",
            printChart : "Print"
          }
        });
        
      Highcharts.chart('container4', {
        chart: {
            spacingTop: 36,
            spacingRight: 24,
            spacingBottom: 24,
            events: {
              load: function () {
                if (this.options.chart.forExport) {
                  this.renderer.image('https://img.favpng.com/1/12/17/anonymous-logo-hacktivism-security-hacker-png-favpng-Yi70kBF3FMQvhjqP2u4Cix8Lg.jpg', 510, 10, 60, 70).add();
                }
              }
            },
            style: {
                fontFamily: 'Roboto, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'
              }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'text'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'text'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Maj', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'unknown'
            },
          },{
             opposite: true,
             title: {
                text: 'Number'
            },
          },{
             visible: false,
             title: {
                text: ' dage'
            },
          },{
             visible: false,
             title: {
                text: ' timer'
            },
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            formatter: function(){var text =  this.x +
                
             '<br/>text1: <b>' + this.points[1].y.toFixed(1).replace('.',',') + ' </b>' +
             '<br/>text2: <b>' + this.points[2].y.toFixed(1).replace('.',',') + ' </b>' +
             '<br/>text3: <b>' + this.points[0].y.toFixed(1).replace('.',',') + ' </b>' +
             '<br/>text4: <b>' + this.points[3].y + ' mm</b>' +
             '<br/>text5: <b>' + precipDays[this.x] + '</b>';
            return text;}
        },
        exporting: {
          //set export size  
          sourceWidth: 1300,
          sourceHeight: 600,
          //Remember times scale: 2 (default)
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    menuItems: buttons.slice(2, 5).concat(buttons.slice(6,7)),
                    enabled: true
                  
                }
            },
            csv: {
                itemDelimiter: ';'
            }
           /*chartOptions: {
              chart: {
                className: 'style-class'
              }
          },*/
        },
            series: [{
            name: 'This is a very long text part',
            zIndex: 1,
            color: '#008FE9',
            marker: {
                  symbol: "circle",
                    fillColor: 'white',
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    lineColor: '#008FE9',
                    radius: 5
                },
            data: [-16.7, -19.1, -19.9, -13.4, -4.5, 0.2, 3, 3, 0.5, -4.2, -8.3, -12.7]
        }, {
            name: 'This is a very long text part1',
            zIndex: 1,
            color: '#FF5151',
            marker: {
                    symbol: "circle",
                    fillColor: 'white',
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    lineColor: '#FF5151',
                    radius: 5
                },
            data: [-10.2, -12.2, -12.8, -6.3, 0.7, 5.2, 8.5, 7.7, 4.2, -0.4, -3.9, -7.2]
        }, {
            name:'This very long Text part2',
            zIndex: 1,
            color: '#7CEEE2',
            marker: {
                    symbol: "circle",
                    fillColor: 'white',
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    lineColor: '#7CEEE2',
                    radius: 5
                },
            data: [-13.4, -15.6, -16.2, -9.6, -1.8, 2.7, 5.7, 5.3, 2.3, -2.3, -6, -9.9]
        }, {
            name: 'this is text4',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            color: '#465EA2',
            data: [16, 16, 18, 20, 18, 24, 27, 34, 37, 29, 37, 26]
        }]
      });
      });
    </script>
```

I hope someone might have a brilliant idea, or something obvious I am overlooking due to a too singledminded focus.

Comment: In summary: you are just looking for an option to export specific items with unique properties while keeping a different base chart? I wonder why the standard export options from API do not meet your requirements? You can give from there your own style and position, and control them as plain HTML (inline styling): https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6L89ft2d/

Comment: Yea, I am trying to export the whole thing, just with a unique property applied only to the series legend text, on export. Thing about the HTML style in the chart option (as I understand it), is that I can only define global values and can't be exact to only the one class I am going for. Overall I might be on the wrong track by trying to use the style class for this - but hoped to avoid going in and creating individual changes for every graph, instead just having the class style set for all.

Comment: Ok, so you would like to work on CSS classes for styled mode, but it would be good to take into account that they are only loaded when exporting the chart: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css . I think you could achieve this by taking into account these parameters in the export options.

Comment: We have gone full circle here. What you are describing is what I tried to do, but I could not figure out how to have the "styled mode" only apply to the export. I could not see an export option that would allow me to do so, but I was in doubt if I misunderstood something, which is why I went looking for another solution and in the end asked. For instance, I was looking at if there was one of those highchart SVG elements that refered only to the situation of export, but no such luck. Which is why I tried the export class e.g.